# Qt menubar not showing

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5

I'm building a simple C++ application on Mac OS X 10.9 with Qt 5.2.1 using CMake (without MOC).

I am starting the executable from the command-line. The problem is that the menu bar is not showing up at all, the Terminal menu bar is still visible but not clickable. When I switch windows temporarily and then come back to the window of this application, I at least see the standard "application" menu with "About". The "About" action is now working and shows the dialog. The toolbar button also works as expected.

What else I tried (and didn't work):

- using the pre-defined `menuBar()`
- use `setMenuBar()`
- `new menuBar(0)`
- `menubar->setVisible(true)`

When I check the `isVisible()` it returns false, also if I set it to visible in the line before.

I wonder whether the lack of using MOC can be the reason for this?

Below I attached a reduced example.

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {

public:

  MainWindow();


private:

  void create_actions_();
  void create_menus_();
  void create_toolbar_();

  void about_();

  QMenuBar* menu_bar_;
  QMenu* file_menu_;
  QMenu* help_menu_;

  QToolBar* file_toolbar_;

  QAction* action_about_;

};



MainWindow::MainWindow() {
  resize(800, 600);

  create_actions_();
  create_menus_();
  create_toolbar_();
}


void MainWindow::create_actions_() {
  action_about_ = new QAction(tr("About"), this);
  connect(action_about_, &QAction::triggered, this, &MainWindow::about_);
}


void MainWindow::create_menus_() {

  menu_bar_ = new QMenuBar(this);

  file_menu_ = menu_bar_->addMenu(tr("&File"));

  menu_bar_->addSeparator();

  help_menu_ = menu_bar_->addMenu(tr("&Help"));
  help_menu_->addAction(action_about_);

  menu_bar_->setNativeMenuBar(true);
}


void MainWindow::create_toolbar_() {

  file_toolbar_ = addToolBar(tr("File"));
  file_toolbar_->addAction(action_about_);

  file_toolbar_->setIconSize(QSize(16, 16));

}


void MainWindow::about_() {
  QMessageBox::about(this, tr("About"), tr("FooBar"));
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  MainWindow main_window;
  main_window.show();

  const int exit_code = app.exec();
  return exit_code;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Core)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Gui)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5OpenGL)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Widgets)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Declarative)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5MacExtras)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(main main.cc)
qt5_use_modules(main Core Gui Widgets Declarative MacExtras)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You're most definitely using moc, you're just not using qmake. Moc is the code generator that is always invoked on each of your files that contain the "Q_OBJECT" macro. Cmake invokes moc for you.

Comment: I am not using MOC; therefore I am also not using Q_OBJECT and signal / slot features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, solved the problem myself. It appears you cannot add a separator to the menubar.

Removing the `menu_bar_->addSeparator();` solved the problem.