# qt menubar not initially visible

Tags: qt, user-interface

I am a new to Qt. A little bit confused with ui, especially uic.

I have created a project to practice Qt: https://github.com/eala/mediaAlgoManager

However, I can't see the menubar when I run it as following:

[image]

The application can't get correct menu bar.
But if I switch to any other applications, and then switch back, it will work correctly.

[image]

I don't know what happened!
I have searched some resources, like [Qt menubar not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744411/qt-menubar-not-showing).

And I think there are some conflicts that there are some GUI design from Qt Designer and some come from codes. I have tried two ways as follows, but still not work.

1. remove setActionMenuBar() function in analyzeGoldenWindow.cpp (add menu bar by codes)
2. remove or add  just in front of status bar in analyzeGoldenWindow.ui

But...the issue is still there....

Comment: Looks like you are creating the menu bar from code, can you post your code?

Comment: in mainWindow constructor, I use following:     mMenuBar = new QMenuBar(this);
    mMenuBar->setNativeMenuBar(true);

    mFileMenu = mMenuBar->addMenu(tr("&File"));
    mNewFileAction = new QAction(tr("&New ..."), this);
    mFileMenu->addAction(mNewFileAction);
    connect(mNewFileAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(newFile()));

Comment: complete codes can be download from
https://github.com/eala/mediaAlgoManager

Answer (score 0):

Call `setMenuBar(mMenuBar)` as the last action in `analyzeGoldenWindow::setActionMenuBar()`. If that fails, try calling `setupUi` before you create the menu.

Comment: still not works...I am not sure what happened. How should I test after I modify some codes every time? I can't find ui_analyzegoldenwindow.h in Finder. So I always right click on the project: (1) Run qMake (2) Rebuild. However, I can't find the proper way to resolve this. I even delete *.pro.user each time.

Comment: it seems not working. Maybe the problem exists when opencv createWindow or something else. I have tried menu role as shown in [link](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/14610/0) which not working either.

Comment: I'll try running your project a bit later.

Comment: Thanks a lot in advance. In the beginning, I selected template "Dialog without buttons" to implement and later I changed by codes to inherit mainWindow. I am not sure if it is related. I created a new mainWindow project and diff with two *.ui files, but nothing I found...